# how to copy GAE application to local launcher?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, drupal, google-compute-engine

I have the drupal app created with one click deployment on GAE. Now I need to modify its code, test with google app Engine Launcher locally and upon completion to deploy back to original app on GAE.

I could ssh to VM and scp the /var/www but there is no app.yaml. How to recover the app into Launcher properly?

Comment: You can't SSH to an App Engine app.

Comment: You might have mixed up [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) with [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/).

Answer (score 1):

Appeared "One click" deploy is a part of GCE(google compute engine). There is no drupal or any another framework except of few demo "hello world" apps on GAE available over local launcher.